# Get the full domain Url from a Asp.Net Web App in a Console App

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, hyperlink, asp.net-mvc-routing, console-application, html-email

Im currently doing a console app that has to send scheduled emails. In one of the emails I have to put the url of the page, something like this:

```
var message = string.Format("Go to our web site
<a href=\"" + "http://" + Request.Url.Authority + Url.Action("action", "Controller", new { requestID = request.ID }) + "\">Click Here</a>");
```

Obviously the Request.Url.Authority will only work in the ASP.Net MVC3 app that I have. But I'm not sure if there is a way to get to the full route name in the console app. Maybe if I reference the web app in the console app... but then I dont know what else to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A console app doesn't run in the context of the website, so you won't have access to anything related to the website.

You can configure this ahead of time though in the app.config file.

```xml
<appSettings>
  <add key="Url" value="http://www.yoursite.com/" />
</appSettings>
```

and in code you can do this to get this value:

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Url"]
```

Comment: Yea I told that to one of my co workers who was absoutely sure that I could have access to the full route, but my guess is that he misunderstood the question. Anyway, I better don't lose time on something like this and just set the value of the domain in the app.config.